# CKEditor v.4 in CodeIgniter 2 project

Tags: codeigniter, view, editor, ckeditor

Is there someone who use CKEditor 4.0 in Codeigniter 2 project? I could find just inbtegrating with CKeditor 3. Very good tutorial, but project structure of forth version is differ from third. Pls, help to integrate ckeditor 4 with codeigniter 2 or pls share some link to tutorial with good explanation.

UPD
I tried this way. I added the following to my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'anons_area' );
</script>

<?php $anons_data = array(
        'name'        => 'anons',
        'id'          => 'anons_area',
        'value'       => 'Введите анонс',
        'rows'        => '10',
        'cols'        => '50',
        'style'       => 'width:50%',
        );
        echo form_textarea($anons_data); ?>
```

but it doesn't work.

UPD2
I found out why editor can't be loaded to browser. Firebug says that access forbiden to ckeditor.js script, You don't have permission to access the requested object.
It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this really isn't hard at all...

Put this in the head of the page you want the ckEditor in, obviously pointing to the correct path for your application:

```
<script src="'.base_url().'assets/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Then in the body where you want the editor:

```
<textarea cols="80" id="editorName" name="editorName" rows="60">

</textarea>
```

At the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorName' );
</script>
```

It's honestly that easy.

Comment: I tried and this did not work - maybe this is for ck 3 ?

Comment: I'm running CK4 doing exactly this.

Comment: Argh, sorry about that, yes I missed a bit. The echo part was missing it's enclosing textarea. Apologies.

Comment: cool thanks for checking. Suggest that you define $newsletterBody in your example so it doesnt break.  I am "getting granular" about this because i went through an ordeal trying to go from ck 3 to ck 4 similar to what she is describing - the codeigniter examples and blog posts are somewhat complicated and only work with ck 3.

Comment: In your example at the bottom what does this js do: CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorName' ); ???

Comment: That's what the CKEditor.js file uses to know which textarea to replace with it's editor. And I removed the $newsletterBody entirely, it has nothing to do with the question, it's just a copy from my own application.

Comment: Ok, so looks like if we add class="ckeditor" then it works without that JS. However you also said "Edit the config.js in the ckEditor folder to point to your paths." But there are not any paths in that config file... That was the other thing i was wondering about in yr answer.

Comment: Mine has a few things in it not relevant to this discussion, but I define my CSS there so I suppose that isn't critically necessary to making it actually work.

Comment: Rick Calder, pls look at updated question. It doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Wooow i did it. I got forbidden error msg because i didn't edit my htaccess file. Now everything is ok. Can you helpme with customizing editor window width? Now it is stretched to full lenght of browser

Comment: I did that too. Thanx guys.

Answer (score 0):

using codeigniter & Ckeditor 4.02 based on code from the ck example page

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

 <?php
 // static example to populate form with text
 $formvalue = "Here is some text to appear in the form box. " ;
 ?> 

 <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"><?php echo $formvalue ?></textarea>
```

You can also use the CI form helper

```
 <?php

 $formvalue = "Here is some text to appear in the form box." ;
 $formdata = array(
      'class'  => 'ckeditor',
          'name'        => 'editor1',
          'id'          => 'SomeID',
          'value'       => $formvalue
        );

 echo form_textarea($formdata) ;
 ?>
```

Next step would be replacing $formvalue with a database result to populate the form (like editing a blog post, etc). 
And if you use the CI Form helper it needs to be loaded first, the easiest is to autoload it in config/autoload.php

Now -- If some brilliant person has some tips on creating a custom tool bar...?

Comment: cartalot, pls look to updated question. I tried but it doesn't work. Any idea?